# Ionic native Facebook logout

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, facebook-graph-api, ionic-framework

I’ve a problem with the Ionic 3 @ionic-native/facebook [`logout()` function](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/facebook/#logout).

This is the workflow:

1. User presses the “LOGOUT” button
2. App calls the `logout()` function
3. `logout()` function removes the Facebook response and sets user to null
4. App redirects the user to login
5. User is automatically logged in again **(Facebook login dialog doesn’t appear like if user login is stored somewhere)**

Why doesn’t the Facebook dialog appear when the user tries to access the app again? Do I have to delete the app’s cookies or storage? If yes, which is it?